# What is the best way to see objects attributes in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I can not find how to see objects attributes in Active Directory in Microsoft Management Console (MMS).
Please tell me if it is possible to do it in  MMS.
I found the Active Directory Explorer that show objects attributes:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx.
Do you know better tools?

*Added After the first answer*

I want to find a simple UI tool that allow browse objects attributes in Active Directory like using Active Directory Explorer:

[image]

If you know LDAP browser that is better that Active Directory Explorer please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ADSIEDIT` tool from the Windows Support Tools is a great tool to "explore" the AD. The `LDP` tool (which is an LDAP browser) will work, too. Any LDAP browser-- GUI or command-line-- will also work. Finally, if command-line tools are your thing take a look at Joe Richards' [wonderful ADFIND tool](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/).

Edit:

It's a bit unclear to me what you're looking for.

It sort of looks like you're just wanting a big flat dump of the attributes associated with some subset of your Directory objects. If that's the case I'd strongly consider looking at Joe Richards' ADFIND. It's pretty easy to dump a subset of the Directory to an LDIF format text file which you can search / view in a very "flat" format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see now that I use `ADSIEDIT`  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx I was not able to see the object attributes at glance. Also, according to what I see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224543 LDP is the command line tool.
Probably I will use Active Directory Explorer

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I dropped on an edit.

Comment: Thanks! I found the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124152%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Open ADUC, Select View from the menu and click "Detail".  This should add a Attribute Editor tab to each object.

Comment: This will only work if you browse to the OU the object is in, and not if you get to it using "Find...".  Which, always annoyed me....

Comment: @Cheekaleak If you've RSAT, try Active Directory Administrative Center (ADAC) instead of ADUC. The properties of a search result have available the Attribute Editor tab -- at the bottom under "Extensions".

Comment: not exactly what the OP wanted, but highly useful